# Databases: Manipulating Weak Entity Sets

Tags: database, entity-framework, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am currently working through some examples of weak entity sets from a textbook for practice and I don't see why you can eliminate the **Customer** entity to help identify the booking for a flight.

The E/R Diagram looks like this
http://prntscr.com/8kv2ok

The full questions goes as follows

- Question 1)  Convert the E/R Diagram of Figure 4.29 to a relational
  database schema [my progress: I managed to finish this question with no trouble]
- Question 2) There is another E/R Diagram that can describe the weak entity set Bookings in Figure 4.29. Notice that a booking can be identified uniquely by the flight number, day of flight,the row, and the seat; the customer is then not necessary to help identify the booking. Revise the diagram from 4.29 to reflect this viewpoint and convert the result you obtain to a relational schema.

My question is then, what would be the relationship between the Booking entity and the Flights entity? And wouldn't eliminating the Customer entity cause problems in identifying specific Customers to specific flights?

Comment: the diagram in your picture is wrong, it's not standard. The `Booking` should have some ID (underlined). `Booking` belongs to a flight, flight has many Bookings, so the relationship here should be `one-many` (one flight has many bookings). Customer has many bookings, booking belongs to just one customer, so the relationship here is also `one-many` (one customer has many bookings). The `Booking` entity should have foreign key `FlightID` and `CustomerID`. Those can become the composite key of `Booking`. Currently all I know is the diagram you posted which is wrong (or not standard).

Comment: Well my professor assigned that problem as an extra practice question so I don't know.

Comment: do you mean the `Figure 4.29` is the diagram you posted from the link? If so how could you complete the question 1? Is there any `Booking` table? If so it should have some ID (as I said) (but the ID is not present in the diagram).

Comment: Yes, and my solution for Question 1 is Bookings(SSNo[PK],number[PK],day[PK],row,seat); Customers(SSNo[PK],name,addr,phone);Flights(number[PK],day[PK],aircraft)

Comment: that looks very similar to what I said, there are still foreign keys to `Customer` and `Flight`. Currently you should make it clear about how `Customer` is eliminated? Do you mean there is not any Customer table?

Comment: Just so you know I'm also on this same problem and I'm also confused by it.